# Set focus to the taskbar

Tags: vb.net, taskbar

I'm writing a simple Visual Basic app to help me launch global hotkeys by the press of a taskbar button.

To do this, I basically set the app to minimize itself back to the taskbar. I then want to activate the taskbar itself (not the previously active program) so I can use SendKeys to do these keypresses. In my test, the keypresses get registered. Its just that I can't seem to find out how to actually activate the taskbar from my program.

If I use AppActivate, I need the processID or the window title.

So it seems best to use Windows API's to do it, but I'm not getting the result I'm after either and I must be doing something wrong.

Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.GotFocus
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        Dim intReturn As Integer = FindWindow("Shell_traywnd", "")
        AppActivate(intReturn)
        SendKeys.Send("%1")
        MsgBox("test")

    End Sub

End Class
```

The error I'm getting is that there's no process by this ID running.

Comment: Fine with me. Can't do that to myself nor do I have enough reputation. Wait, I can flag, not vote close... I just flagged it as dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FindWindow will return a hwnd handle, not a processID. You will need to use the function SetForegroundWindow to activate it.

Your code becomes as follows:

```
Public Class Form1
    Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Integer
    Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.GotFocus
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        Dim intReturn As Integer = FindWindow("Shell_traywnd", "")
        SetForegroundWindow(intReturn)
        SendKeys.Send("%1")
        MsgBox("test")

    End Sub

End Class
```